# How to click edit button present in the tools icon of the specific image when there are 100 images present in the same webpage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

How to click edit button present in the tools icon of the specific image when there are 100 images present in the same webpage?

There is a webpage in the above URL, Which has 100's of images in it, I need to pick any image from there and click on settings icon present in image pane, once i select i will get 2 options , ie edit and delete ... so i need to click either edit or delete option.. How to do it?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Whad do you need? I dont understand

Comment: Share code you tried so far

Comment: As it stands now, this question is likely to be voted for closure as "too broad".  The question reads more like a requirements list than an actual problem, and a link to a website published somewhere isn't a substitute for providing a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: besides the fact that I don't think **any** of the tags in use are even valid.  The site appears to be using `ng-reflect`, which is Angular2 (not angularjs), and TypeScript.  And the other 3 tags are 3 different testing frameworks, but the question has nothing to do with testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 2):

You should not click on the whole image but just on "Settings" icon:

```
$("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog").click();
element(by.linkText("Delete")).click();
```

Comment: Yes @Andersson, I tried the same way                                                           $("i.glyphicon.glyphicon-cog").click();
 element(by.linkText("Delete")).click();                                                        It is not showing any error, but action s not performing on the Webpage, It may because of "more than one element found on the same page" Donno how to fix it

Comment: Try more specific selector `element(by.xpath("//a[text()='Unisex Made in the USA Jersey Short-Sleeve T-Shirt']/preceding::i[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog']")).click();`

Comment: Thats great @Andersson, Working Cool... Thanks a ton